# Remove names of Countries etc. from Leaflet Map R

Tags: r, leaflet

do you know how can I remove names of countries etc. from Leaflet map in R?

```
leaflet(quakes) %>% addTiles()
```

I want to have clear map, without text

Answer (score 10):

If you want a basemap of a particular style you need to find a provider that provides one. The default is OpenStreetMap.

Stamen (http://maps.stamen.com) provide alternative base maps, and this might be what you want:

```
> terrain = "http://tile.stamen.com/terrain-background/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg"
> leaflet(quakes) %>% addTiles(terrain)
```

but make sure you credit Stamen correctly for usage.

Many other alternative base maps are available. I usually fire up QGIS and see what's in the QuickMapServices plugin for a long list.

Maybe Carto's light-nolabels looks right:

```
> carto = "http://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
> leaflet(quakes) %>% addTiles(carto)
```

again, credit Carto properly when publishing.

Comment: Nice and clean. Thanks a lot.